# MySQL "LOAD DATA INFILE" and Missing Double Quotes

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to load a CSV into MySQL using the LOAD DATA INFILE technique.  It's working fine, but I have a problem where some columns use double quotes and some do not.

Example:

```
something,123,something,"Bauer, Jack",123,something
```

What happens is the commas inside the quotes break the import, so my data is all jacked up at the end.  Not sure how to get the import to escape commas inside the double quotes.

```
mysql --user=<USER> --password=<PASS> -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '<FILENAME>' INTO TABLE <TABLENAME> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (col1, col2, col3, ...)" <DATABASE>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to execute the statement LOAD DATA INFILE with the additional option

```
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Thus the whole statement becoming

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '<FILENAME>' INTO TABLE <TABLENAME>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(col1, col2, col3, ...)
```

For further readings, please consult the excellent [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) e.g. for MySQL 5.1 GA.

Comment: very helpful your answer +1

Comment: Is there a way to remove quotes optionally ?

Comment: very helpful, thank you. I had `FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`and the repetition of `FIELDS` caused the error. MySQL is unforgiving.

Comment: If this option doesn’t seem to work check the encoding of the file. MySQL is unable “to load data files that use the ucs2, utf16, utf16le, or utf32 character set.”

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have figured out what to do by now, but If you haven't hopefully this will help you out.

I have had trouble in Excel 2007 exporting to a customized CSV file. I found that you can change the fields terminator here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1635599&page=15

I prefer to use the pipe | character as it is uncommon, and a little more flexible when dealing with inch", foot" measurements.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Excel