# Loading csv with quotes into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file with some fields within double quotes, as they contain commas within them. Sample data:

```
ID, NAME, ADDRESS  
1, Tom Jones, "Home, 123 Ave, TX"
2, John Thomas, "Office, 321 St TX"
```

I tried to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904909/mysql-load-data-infile-and-missing-double-quotes#), using `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` to load the data to my DB but I keep getting

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'' at line 1
```

My load command is as follows:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
'C:\Users\Craig\Downloads\de1\Data\contacts.csv'
INTO TABLE TEST1.contacts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That looks good, so is it possible there's something wonky in your SQL query like an invisible character?

Comment: Well for some reason when I issued the command in a single line, it worked like magic. smh.

Comment: It was probably an invisible character. Those can show up from time to time if you copy-paste from one program to another.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you SQL both in navicat and cmd.exe. I got the same error on cmd.exe as yours, but worked well on navicat. The key is symbol "" on you file path in SQL. You should replace backslash with slash.
Just like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
'C:/Users/Craig/Downloads/de1/Data/contacts.csv'
INTO TABLE TEST1.contacts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
;
```