# MySQL LOAD FILE With Lines Ending With TRIPLE Double Quotes

Tags: mysql, csv

Trying to load a CSV file into MySQL, using LOAD DATA:

```
load data local infile 'myfile' into table `mytable`
fields terminated by ',' ESCAPED BY '' optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines
```

My situation is similar to this guy's here:
[LOAD DATA from CSV file where doublequote was used as the escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053530/load-data-from-csv-file-where-doublequote-was-used-as-the-escape-character)

and this guy's here:
[MySQL "LOAD DATA INFILE" and Missing Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904909/mysql-load-data-infile-and-missing-double-quotes)

but combined into one. I have OCCASIONALLY quoted strings (specifically, whenever there is a comma in the string, since that is my field delimiter), but I ALSO have double double-quoted strings, where the string had quotes in it, so it added TWO sets of double quotes.

The problem is, whenever the string ENDS in double-quoted strings, AND there is a comma in it somewhere, it becomes a TRIPLE double-quoted string. this seems to give MySQL a seizure, and it just keeps loading the next line and the next line, until the field runs out of memory, at which point it jumps ahead by about 30,000 lines, effectively SKIPPING large swaths of data.

I tried escaping the double-quotes, but the problem still happens. I also tried replacing the start and end quotes (when they exist) with other characters, but according to the LOAD DATA manual, you can only use ASCII characters as "enclosers", and a lot of the ASCII characters are actually in use in the data, and the others (such as those in the EXTENDED ASCII range) don't seem to work.

So is there some trick I'm missing? I've honestly never imported to MySQL from CSV before, so I apologize if the answer is something obvious, but I've spent a few hours trying to figure it out, and the last hour looking up possible solutions here. So thanks in advance (I hope).

Here is an example line:

```
3,"words words words, ""words in quotes"""
```

Comment: Indeed, there might be cases of input that so confuses MySQL that it can't import that file. You might have to write some custom code to rewrite the CSV file into a format that MySQL can understand, then you can import it. This isn't rocket science.

Comment: That verbal explanation is quite convoluted, could you give a simple example of a line that is giving you trouble?

Comment: *this seems to give MySQL a seizure, and it just keeps loading the next line and the next line, until the field runs out of memory, at which point it jumps ahead by about 30,000 lines, effectively SKIPPING large swaths of data.* impossible. After opening dquote MySQl assumes each doubled dquote as quoted single dquote until single dquote meet. If MySQL loads the next lines as a part of current line then the dquote chars balance is broken in current line. Check - the amount of total non-slashed (`\"`) dquote chars in each line must be even.

Comment: Just updated the question with an example string. It doesn't seem to matter if I put a space in between the last double double-quotes and the ending double quote or not. It still does exactly as I mentioned above.

Comment: `LOAD DATA ( "words words words, ""words in quotes""" )` => `'words words words, "words in quotes"'`

Comment: @Akina: that's fine, but in order to avoid issues with my apostrophes, that means I need to have them escaped, which means i have to change my code to have escape character: ESCAPED BY '\\' optionally enclosed by '\'' and I changed the double double-quotes to escaped double quotes. But now my code does NOTHING. It doesn't add a single line to the database. Any thoughts? For the record, my example code now looks like this: 'words words words, \"words in quotes\" '

Comment: a good editor or linux tool öoke sed awk  will get your wanted result better

Comment: @Akina well, it turns out you don't need to escape the '\n' for lines terminated by '\n'. Even so, it is STILL glitching on the lines that end in single quotes. The glitched entry looks like this: words words words, "words in quotes" '   ... and continues adding the remaining lines until it runns out of memory for that column entry. Just what is going on??? I KNOW it has a \n at the end of the line, because I used a special text editor to find them, and every line has one...