# Need a Column Delimiter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, delimiter, import-csv

I am very new to MySQL. I am trying to load a CSV file into MySQL Table.

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/fg/Downloads/test.csv' into table my_schema.my_table
fields terminated by ','
escaped by '"'
ignore 1 rows;
```

The problem is that I do not know how to apply a Column Delimiter because, for example I have a column containing this value "Adam Steven & David, Brown". Due to the Fields terminated by ',' the value is separated into two "Adam Steven & David" and "Brown". Any ideas how I can apply a Column Delimiter?

Note: Only the values with several names have double quotes. Those with one name do not have double quotes. If I apply `ENCLOSED BY` clause, it imports only the values with double quotes. The `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` is acting the same way as `ENCLOSED BY` for some unclear reason.

Comment: Are your values enclosed by double quotes?  If so, ensure you add an `ENCLOSED BY` clause in your statement.  See example at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Only the values with several names. Those with one name do not have double quotes. If I apply ENCLOSED BY clause, it imports only the values with double quotes.

Comment: It's normal in CSV to have *optional* quoting on fields, as in `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL "LOAD DATA INFILE" and Missing Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904909/mysql-load-data-infile-and-missing-double-quotes)

Comment: OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY is acting the same way as just ENCLOSED BY.